# Browserify uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am using browserify to be able to use the validator npm module client side. I have linked the bundle.js file created by browserify to the HTML page I would like to use the validator module on.

Here is the code from my bundle.js file:

```
const validator = require('validator');

console.log('Before function');

function validEmail() {
    // var email = document.getElementById('contact_details').value;
    // console.log(email);
    alert('hi');
};

console.log('After function');
```

Within the bundle.js file I have created a function, however when I call the function within the HTML page it comes up with this error, here is the console output from the HTML page:

```
bundle.js:4 Before function
bundle.js:12 After function
general-work:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: validEmail is not defined(…)
```

The two console logs both run correctly showing that the file is linked and is reading the code from the bundle.js file, but for some reason it is not allowing me to run the function saying it isn't defined.

Thanks

Comment: Just use the `<input type="email">` and you wont need any large 3th party validator lib, beside i think borwsers dose a hella lot better at validating then any other lib out there

Comment: If you've declared the `validEmail` function within a Browserified module, it'll be local to that module and not global - hence the error about its not being defined.

Comment: @cartant How would I make the function global?